# How come debts is higher than assets?

Tags: debt

Investopedia has a [definition about Debt ratio](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/debtratio.asp), I do not understand how come Debt ratio can be higher than 1. Because it means that equity is negative (because Total Assets=Debt+Equity).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equity can be negative when a firm accumulates losses and [liabilities exceed the number of assets](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/08/negative-shareholder-equity.asp). In that case debt ratio can be bigger than 1.